# column-count + column-width + break-before behaves very differently across browsers

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

I've discovered some signifiant differences in browser behavior when combining column-count with column-width and break-before.

The following displays as 3 columns in Safari, 2 columns in Chrome, and 1 column in Firefox.  The columns are each the browser width, and not 3.75in, so right scrolling becomes necessary to see them.

`column-count: 1` is set just to highlight the issue.  Goal is for it to be `column-count: 2`, and then responsively degrade to 1 column for narrow browsers (i.e. less than 7.5in).  That is why the `break-before: column` is there, as I want DIV 3 to always start on a new column, when it's wide enough to show 2 columns.  I know the `break-before: column` is not needed for DIV 1, but left it in to highlight the issue.

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div style="column-count: 1; column-width: 3.75in;">
         <div>
            <div style="break-before: column;">
               <div>DIV 1</div>
            </div>
            <div style="break-inside:avoid; ">Div 1 Div 1 Div 1 Div 1 Div 1 Div 1 Div 1 Div 1 Div 1 Div 1 Div 1 Div 1 </div>
         </div>
         <div style="break-inside:avoid;">
            <div>DIV 2</div>
            <div style="break-inside:avoid; ">Div 2 Div 2 Div 2 Div 2 Div 2 Div 2 Div 2 Div 2 Div 2 Div 2 Div 2 Div 2 </div>
         </div>
         <div style="break-inside:avoid;">
            <div style="break-before: column;">
               <div>DIV 3</div>
            </div>
            <div style="break-inside:avoid; ">Div 3 Div 3 Div 3 Div 3 Div 3 Div 3 Div 3 Div 3 Div 3 Div 3 Div 3 Div 3 </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Firefox has the behavior I'm expecting, for them to all be displayed as 1 column.  Any insight into why Chrome is different and Safari is even more different?